# DejaVu Backup not working for google drive

Tags: backup, deja-dup, duplicity

I've recently tried switching the google drive i upload my backups to, but now the backup utility (deja-dup) just isn't working. When I try to make a backup, it would scan, and then time out with

```
Giving up after 5 attempts. timeout: The read operation timed out
```

How would I go about troubleshooting this and debugging?
I've tried removing all my online accounts and adding the new google account i want to use. (both google and ubuntu one) I've also tried reinstalling `duplicity` and `deja-dup`, and resetting all my settings for deja-dup. Nothing has worked so far, and there aren't any error messages when I run `deja-dup` from the terminal.

Edit 1:

As codlord suggested, I ran deja dup with `DEJA_DUP_DEBUG` set. Here's the log output:

```
....


DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . Added incremental Backupset (start_time: Thu Nov  5 07:57:24 2020 / end_time: Thu Nov 12 08:05:49 2020)

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Added set Thu Nov 12 08:05:49 2020 to pre-existing chain [Thu Aug 20 18:47:31 2020]-[Thu Nov 12 08:05:49 2020]

DUPLICITY: NOTICE 1
DUPLICITY: . Synchronizing remote metadata to local cache...

DUPLICITY: NOTICE 1
DUPLICITY: . Copying duplicity-full-signatures.20200821T014731Z.sigtar.gz to local cache.

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Registering (mktemp) temporary file /tmp/duplicity-2izahox3-tempdir/mktemp-aww0pdv8-2

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . PyDrive backend: found file 'duplicity-full-signatures.20200821T014731Z.sigtar.gz' with id 135UZSkFvRDv7egAogXy6MYaHiH3iopqN on server, adding to cache

DUPLICITY: DEBUG 1
DUPLICITY: . Backtrace of previous error: Traceback (innermost last):
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 376, in inner_retry
DUPLICITY: .     return fn(self, *args)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backend.py", line 570, in get
DUPLICITY: .     self.backend._get(remote_filename, local_path)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/duplicity/backends/pydrivebackend.py", line 186, in _get
DUPLICITY: .     drive_file.GetContentFile(util.fsdecode(local_path.name))
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 210, in GetContentFile
DUPLICITY: .     self.FetchContent(mimetype, remove_bom)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 43, in _decorated
DUPLICITY: .     return decoratee(self, *args, **kwargs)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 255, in FetchContent
DUPLICITY: .     self.content = io.BytesIO(self._DownloadFromUrl(download_url))
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydrive/auth.py", line 75, in _decorated
DUPLICITY: .     return decoratee(self, *args, **kwargs)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pydrive/files.py", line 503, in _DownloadFromUrl
DUPLICITY: .     resp, content = self.http.request(url)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 173, in new_request
DUPLICITY: .     resp, content = request(orig_request_method, uri, method, body,
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 280, in request
DUPLICITY: .     return http_callable(uri, method=method, body=body, headers=headers,
DUPLICITY: .   File "/home/grant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1985, in request
DUPLICITY: .     (response, content) = self._request(
DUPLICITY: .   File "/home/grant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1650, in _request
DUPLICITY: .     (response, content) = self._conn_request(
DUPLICITY: .   File "/home/grant/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1589, in _conn_request
DUPLICITY: .     response = conn.getresponse()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1347, in getresponse
DUPLICITY: .     response.begin()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 307, in begin
DUPLICITY: .     version, status, reason = self._read_status()
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 268, in _read_status
DUPLICITY: .     line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socket.py", line 669, in readinto
DUPLICITY: .     return self._sock.recv_into(b)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1241, in recv_into
DUPLICITY: .     return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
DUPLICITY: .   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1099, in read
DUPLICITY: .     return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
DUPLICITY: .  socket.timeout: The read operation timed out
DUPLICITY: . 

DUPLICITY: WARNING 1
DUPLICITY: . Attempt 1 failed. timeout: The read operation timed out

DUPLICITY: INFO 1
DUPLICITY: . PyDrive backend: found file 'duplicity-full-signatures.20200821T014731Z.sigtar.gz' with id 135UZSkFvRDv7egAogXy6MYaHiH3iopqN in ID cache


.... // at this point the error would repeat 4 more times and deja-dup would give up.
```

This seems to indicate that deja-dup is able to access my drive but some read op isn't working?
I checked my drive and the file `duplicity-full-signatures.20200821T014731Z.sigtar.gz` doesn't seem to exist. Maybe deja-dup is trying to read it but it can't since it doesn't exist? How would i fix this?

Comment: You can get some (very verbose) debug logging on the console by setting the environment variable `export DEJA_DUP_DEBUG=1` before you run deja-dup. Which may (or may not) help you.

Comment: Hm, this isn't documented anywhere I could find. Should this be added to `deja-dup` man pages or something?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to your question as such but an alternative that may solve your issue - a google drive mount that pretty much looks and acts like any other mount or hard drive. I use `deja-up` to backup files to drive this way and never had any issues.

I had numerous problems in the past using Google drive in Ubuntu with it's built-in support. It may do the basics but that's about it. So I moved to using `google-drive-ocamlfuse` from here: https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

All details are on the github product page but I think this is what I did:

Install package google-drive-ocamlfuse:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install google-drive-ocamlfuse
```

Web browser login to get access tokens:

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse -label YOUR_GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_HERE
```

Create a mount point:

```
mkdir /home/wherever/Documents/mygoogledrive
```

Mount:

```
google-drive-ocamlfuse -label mygoogledrive /home/wherever/Documents/mygoogledrive
```

And use `fusermount -u /home/wherever/Documents/mygoogledrive` to unmount or `fusermount -uz /home/wherever/Documents/mygoogledrive` for lazy unmount if -u does not work.

Personally I just have a startup script which runs the unmount and mount command, then if I ever get any issues I just re-run the script.

Comment: Actually, looking at my backup script now I actually deja-dup locally then use `rsync` to sync the backup files to my google drive mount.

Comment: Would you please share (the relevant parts of) your startup script? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. The first time, it finally disappeared, probably because of variable Google Drive response time. When manually copying files that `duplicity` want to download in its cache, this was taking slightly over 30 seconds, which is, I think, the default time out value used in `pydrive` and/or the underlying libraries `httplib2` and `http` used to download the file. That delay was the response time, because once the ~ 50 MB file transfer starts, it takes about a second to complete.

I could identify this cause and temporarily work around this error by hard-coding a 60 seconds time out in `duplicity`'s `pydrivebackend.py` ([see on GitLab](https://gitlab.com/duplicity/duplicity/-/blob/master/duplicity/backends/pydrivebackend.py)), at the 3 places where it instantiates `GoogleAuth()`, i.e. `GoogleAuth(http_timeout=60)`.

This is not a permanent solution. If it comes back, I guess we should dig at a way to specify a higher HTTP/Google Drive API request time out value in `deja-dup` x `duplicity` x `pydrive`.

I hope this helps and please let me know if you have any question.